# scrapinghub requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://storage.scrapinghub.com

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I am trying to run [scrapy_price_monitor](https://github.com/stummjr/scrapy_price_monitor#running-in-a-local-environment) in local environment, but when I give the command "scrapy crawl spidername", it returns "unauthorized" when trying to send the item to storage.scrapinghub.

I have already succesfully "shub login" (added my apikey) and succesfully deployed the project {proj_id} with "shub deploy {proj_id}".

> File "/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapinghub/hubstorage/client.py", line 107, in invoke_request
>       r.raise_for_status()
>
> File "/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/scrapy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
>
> raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
>   requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://storage.scrapinghub.com/collections/{proj_id}/s/spidername

Comment: Did you put {proj_id} in that URL or is that the actual output of your error? If so it looks like your proj_id var is not being substituted into the URL...

Comment: Its just a placeholder. I put it to make the references clearer. In reality there is an integer in place of {proj_id}